Indicating one way trail direction with arrows in leaflet and OSM
I am currently working on a trail mapping Next.js react app where I fetch data from OpenStreetMap and illustrate trails on a map using leaflet polyline. Some trails have the tag oneway= 'yes' which I would like to represent visually using arrows on the polyline itself, that way it would be easy to tell which direction each trail went.
I have searched and tried many different avenues to try and replicate this feature in my app, using leaflet plugins such as leaflet-polylineDecorator or leaflet-arrowheads. I even tried rendering a bunch of markers and rotating them to point towards the next node, but I didn't manage to make it work and it seemed too complicated a solution for something so simple.
I am looking at implementing a simple and lightweight solution to avoid slowing the app down. Is there an easy solution which I am missing?

You can relatively easy adding decoration with leaflet.polylineDecorator.
You'll need to create a decorator for each feature that is oneway = 'yes'. I recommend to add the decorators to a separate L.FeatureGroup (instead to the map directly) so you can easily remove, show or hide them depending on the zoom level.
Here is an example (using vanilla JavaScript and a test GeoJSON with polylines and a property oneway; it will require some adaptation to your dataset and for Next.js):
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>StackOverflow Question 79028922 - Trail Directions</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet.css" />
    <script src="leaflet.js"></script>

    <script src="leaflet.polylineDecorator.js"></script>

    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }

        #map {
            height: 100vh;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="map"></div>

    <script>

        const coordinate = [46.948056, 7.4475];

        const map = L.map('map').setView(coordinate, 15);

        L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            maxZoom: 22,
            // add link to attribution, omitted in this code example
            // due to width limit, i.e., avoid horizontal scrolling
            attribution: '&copy; OpenStreetMap',
        }).addTo(map);

        fetch('trails.geojson')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(trails => {

                const trailLayer = L.geoJSON(trails, {
                    style: (feature) => {
                        const isOneWay = feature.properties['oneway'] == 'yes';
                        return {
                            color: isOneWay ? '#a14242' : '#160042',
                        };
                    }, 
                }).addTo(map);

                // create decorators
                const decorators = trailLayer.getLayers()
                    .filter(layer => layer.feature.properties['oneway'] == 'yes')
                    .map(layer => {

                        // swap lat/lon (needed as GeoJSON uses a different order)
                        const coordinates = layer.feature.geometry.coordinates
                            .map(c => [c[1], c[0]]);

                        // create the decorator for the trail
                        return L.polylineDecorator(L.polyline(coordinates), {
                            patterns: [{ 
                                offset: '5%', 
                                repeat: '50px', 
                                symbol: L.Symbol.arrowHead({ 
                                    pixelSize: 10, 
                                    polygon: false, 
                                    pathOptions: { 
                                        stroke: true, 
                                        color: '#a14242' 
                                    } 
                                }) 
                            }]
                        });

                    });

                const featureGroup = L.featureGroup(decorators, {}).addTo(map);

                map.on('zoom', event => {
                    featureGroup.clearLayers();
                    if (map.getZoom() >= 15) {
                        decorators.forEach(decorator => {
                            featureGroup.addLayer(decorator);
                        });
                    }
                });

            });

    </script>

</body>

</html>

The file trails.geojson can be found here.
I also uploaded the code to a GitHub repository here and a demo can be found here.

I think using a library such as leaflet.polylineDecorator or leaflet-arrowheads is probably the most lightweight solution as you would need to manipulate the SVG paths manually otherwise.

Addendum: In leaflet.polylineDecorator's README.md there is a section recommending two light-weight alternatives for simpler cases. Leaflet.TextPath could be worth to be investigated.

Thank you for your example, it helped me understand .geojson files at the same time! I ended up making it work, for anyone wondering I will answer my own question.

I ended up solving the issue I had with the leaflet-polylineDecorator not being found even after installing.
You have to run :
pnpm install --save-dev @types/leaflet-polylinedecorator
I then created a react component in which I added a useEffect hook to add the decorator to the map
and then added it into my map component.
